# More efficient strategy than randomly selecting rows that meet condition in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, algorithm

Imagine I would like to develop something similar to Tinder. I have a database with roughly 170k rows (=persons) and I would like to present them on my website. After the user's response, the next person is shown etc.

Once a person has been shown, this is marked in the column 'seen' with a 1. The order in which the persons are shown should be random and only persons that have not been seen yet should be shown.

At the moment, I have this solution. However, this is rather slow and takes too much time for a smooth experience. What would be a more efficient approach to this problem? What is the gold standard for such problems?

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE (seen = 0) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Is there any index present on the column being queried (here 'seen')

Comment: @WisdomSeeker Each row has an index, yes. I don't know exactly what you mean with an index on the column.

Comment: Not primary key. Index as in a non-clustered index on 'seen' column. Also `order by rand()` on big datasets might have a performance cost.

Comment: I see. I certainly could add an index to seen, yes. How could this help me?

Comment: In simpler terms, adding an index on column makes querying on that column faster.

Comment: Thanks! I added an index to the column. However, it still takes several seconds to get a result. I was hoping for a more general approach to such problems.

Answer (score 1):

Add a non-clustered index on the 'seen' column and PK column which will improve querying on the same.

If the primary id is sequential and u know the limits of the records, you can get a random number between max value and min value and query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM data 
WHERE seen = 0 AND id >= random_id 
LIMIT 1
```